# UWP and Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client Release configuration problem

Tags: c#, uwp, release, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using UWP application as client app, which communicate with server through SignalR.

After I have upgraded Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 3.0.3 to 3.1.2 version, communication in the UWP app stop working. Strange thing is that communication works in debug mode but in the release it can't send message to server or even receive message from the server.

Only message in the log file that I've got when try to send message is:

*System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException: This operation cannot be carried out because metadata for the following object was removed for performance reasons:\n\n  EETypeRva:0x00135980\n\nNo further information is available. Rebuild in debug mode for better information.*

I have found some solutions for this error but anything haven't helped.

On the receiving messages I get exceptions:

*Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException' in System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll*

*Exception thrown: 'System.IO.InvalidDataException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json.dll*

It seems like SignalR at that moment do disconnect from the server and connect again.

Other clients like web application which listen for the same messages work perfectly.

Do I need some additional setup for the release mode or problem is in update?

**Note:** In Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 3.0.3 everything works perfectly fine, and code is the same.

Comment: Hi, is your connected URL is `https`? Does switching to `http` work? I found a [similar question](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13767) that might help you. However, there is currently no definite conclusion. If it is not necessary, you can temporarily fall back to version 3.0.3.

Comment: Hi, connected URL is http, yes I've already put it back to 3.0.3 because I haven't managed to find solution. However if I find solution I will post it here, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

.NET Native runtime is optimizing things away on release configuration. To find out which member the compiler should keep, go to project properties > build > Enable .NET Native. For SignalR, try to add this to your Properties\Default.rd.xml file:

```
<Type Name="System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.JsonConverterString" Dynamic="Required All" />
<Type Name="System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.JsonConverterUri" Dynamic="Required All" />
<Type Name="System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.JsonConverterBoolean" Dynamic="Required All" />
<Type Name="System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.JsonConverterInt32" Dynamic="Required All" />
<Type Name="System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.JsonConverterDouble" Dynamic="Required All" />
<Type Name="System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.JsonConverterInt16" Dynamic="Required All" />
<Type Name="System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.JsonConverterByte" Dynamic="Required All" />
<Type Name="System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.JsonConverterDecimal" Dynamic="Required All" />
<Type Name="System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.JsonConverterGuid" Dynamic="Required All" />
<Type Name="System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.JsonConverterEnum" Dynamic="Required All" />
<Type Name="System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.JsonConverterDateTime" Dynamic="Required All" />
<Type Name="System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.JsonConverterDateTimeOffset" Dynamic="Required All" />
```